# Capacitor sign in with apple is not working

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am using Capacitor sign in with apple to login with Apple, this is my code:

```
registerApple(apple: string) {
   SignInWithApple.authorize().then(resp => {
      this.loginSocial(resp);
      console.log("respuesta", resp.response);
      if (this.error === true) {
        this.activateTabMenu(true);
        this.navCtrl.navigateRoot("/home");
      } else {
        this.register(resp.response, resp.response.user, null, null);
        this.user.socialType = apple;
        this.viewMode = "view1";
        this.progressValue = 0.3;
        this.dataDepTp();
     }
  }).catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

the thing is that when I test it it doesn't work, the Apple GUI doesn't open, and the xcode console prints the next message:

```
[log] - {"code":"UNIMPLEMENTED"}
```

I also already enable the Sign In with Apple in xcode and apple developers

what can I do?

Comment: Check this link https://ionicframework.com/blog/adding-sign-in-with-apple-to-an-ionic-app/

Comment: that is the tutorial that I am following, I have done everything that is in the tutorial and it shows the [log] - {"code":"UNIMPLEMENTED"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run on physical device or on macOS, iOS has a few issues with this plugin - https://github.com/capacitor-community/apple-sign-in/issues/23

**The following example is Capacitor 3/4 related**

Signin with apple requires an options field with a nonce.

The example below uses firebase and npm sha.js

Have a look at the https://github.com/capacitor-community/apple-sign-in docs

Also, the Firebase Apple Sign-in Setup guide explains the apple email relay config - [https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple?authuser=0&hl=en'](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/apple?authuser=0&hl=en%27)

```js
 async loginApple() {
        if (this.platform.is('capacitor')) {
          const rawNonce = 'any random string will do here';
          const nonce = shajs('sha256').update(rawNonce).digest('hex');
          const options: SignInWithAppleOptions = {
            clientId: 'com.example.app',
            redirectURI: 'https://your-app-name.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler',
            scopes: 'email name',
            state: '123456',
            nonce,
          };

          try {
            const { response } = await SignInWithApple.authorize(options);
            console.log('app:auth: loginApple response - ', response);
          }
       }
}
```